# Rails model multiple has_many :through relationships output to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following data models and would like to render a json hash that includes information from each model. For example, client.id, client.name_first, client, name_last, every workout description for each client and each exercise description for each workout.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :trainer
  has_many :programs
  has_many :workouts, :through => :programs
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
  has_many :clients, :through => :programs
  has_many :routines
  has_many :exercises, :through => :routines
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :routines
  has_many :workouts, :through => :routines
end
```

My database migrations:

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.integer :account_id
      t.integer :trainer_id
      t.string :name_first
      t.string :name_last
      t.string :phone

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateWorkouts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :workouts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :trainer_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :exercises do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :media

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am able to return the workouts for a particular client:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:id])
clients_workouts = @client.workouts.select('workouts.*,programs.client_id').group_by(&:client_id)
render json: clients_workouts
```

And I am able to return the exercises for a particular workout:

```
@workout =  Workout.find(params[:id])
exercises_workouts = @workout.exercises.select('exercises.*, routines.workout_id').group_by(&:workout_id)
render json: exercises_workouts
```

However, I do not know how to return the data with information from all three tables (Client, Workout, Exercise) included (joined through Programs and Routines). Is this possible? And how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm not really sure what's happening in your query:

```
clients_workouts = @client.workouts.select('workouts.*,programs.client_id').group_by(&:client_id)
```

Is this not sufficient?

```
@client.workouts
```

Now, on to the answer... assuming I'm still following:

ActiveRecord offers a `.to_json` method, which is what's being implicitly called here. The explicit version would be e.g.

```
render json: clients_workouts.to_json
```

Knowing that, you can look up `to_json` in the api (here's some good documentation even though it shows as deprecated: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json). But, basically, the answer is to start with the root object -- the client I believe -- and build the included objects and attributes/methods from there in the options hash.

```
render json: @client.to_json(include: { workouts: { include: :exercises } })
```

You can customize which attributes or methods are included from each related model if needed, just dig into the documentation a little. Have fun!

Comment: @client.workouts returns almost the same thing. My query also returned the client id as a key to the workouts array. Your solution was exactly what I was looking for. I was making it too complicated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Very possible and their are different ways to optain this.

One, without any 3rd party library is to use includes, just as if you were solving an n+1 problem or…

Use a much cooler approach and use active model serializers

[Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)